# How do I make my custom file-type upgradeable?

Tags: c#, file, .net-4.0

I have a custom file type associated with my application, where I save a class instance by simply serializing it to a file.

I want to be able to upgrade my application by adding more properties to the class, and perhaps also removing properties. How can I get the old version of the application to work with the new files - whatever it can get of them, and more importantly, how can I get a new version of the application to use the old files? Is there any common practice for achieving this goal?

I'm asking this *before* the first version is published - How do I make the file-type easily upgradeable?

(Googling ran into a lot of "noise".)

Comment: May be this could help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @yogi You can make your comment into an answer. It looks promissing.

Comment: No. A link is not an answer. If @yogi can summarize the contents of the page (and link to it), that would make an answer.

Comment: I think there are two ways - you can use something like Version Tolerant Serialization as mentioned by yogi or you can make conversion to new format - Visual Studio, Royal TS and I think many more do the following :)

Comment: Thanks yogi, I didn't know about that before.  That will become extremely useful for me at some point, I'm sure.

Comment: @Giedrius You can make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two ways

- you can use something like [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as mentioned by yogi
- or you can make conversion to new format - Visual Studio, Royal TS and I think many more do the following.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out a C# implementation of Protocol Buffers. It's a type of serialization developed by google (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) It uses id's for propery identification. So You serialized data is not binded by property names etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking before the first version is published I come in time to tell you this: You won't be happy with the BinaryFormatter in the long term. **I think you should separate your storage object model from your "operational objects".**

Just serializing the runtime state of a program is meant as an easy serialization method but it prevents from making significant changes to those objects *ever* again.

I think proto-buf is nice as the versioning path is very clear. Also, XmlSerializer serialized classes are nice as they are readable.